# Uploading image from Gallery android application

Tags: java, android, xml

Welcome everyone, 
My applicatoin needs to retrieve any picture from the gallery.. I searched in  Google
then I found a simple code as shown below+ my code, i used it in my application it works ( it goes to Gallery when i press browse button) but i don't know if it retrieves the picture or not
because as you know the emulator doesn't have any images i was trying to add picture to 
the emulator (By using DDMS) but I couldn't, so I don't know if these functions in this code ( onActivityResult() and String getPath() ) retrieve the selected picture?

Q1:If yes please infrom me how can I add it to Case Object (it's a class in my Project)
?

```
public class MyCase {


    //private ?? pic;
    private String name;
    private String gender ;
    private int age;
    private String clothes;
    private String MoreInfo;
    private String time;
    private String location;
    private  int ID;
}
```

Q2: what shall use of data type for Case picture?

thanks so much ,,

```
public class CreateNewForm extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener  {


        Button Browse, Cancelb, Nextb;
        ImageView  CasePic;
        Spinner CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM;
        TextView tesst;
        RadioGroup GenderSelection;
        EditText CaseName, CaseClothes, CaseMoreInfo, CaseAge;

        //For Browsering Picture 
        private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
        private String selectedImagePath;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_new_form);

            //To Call initializer Function 
            initializer();

            // 1-For Uploading Picture
            Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                    // select a file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });


    }

    // To initialize the variables 
    private void initializer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //This information will be filled by a plaintiff
                //CasePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                CaseName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseNm);
                GenderSelection= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                CaseAge= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseaage);
                tesst= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                CaseDurationH= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Shr);
                CaseDurationM= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Smin);
                CaseClothes= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseClothes);
                CaseMoreInfo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseMrInfo);
                CasePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casepic);
                Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browseCasePic);
                Nextb= (Button)findViewById(R.id.next1);
                Cancelb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel1);
    }

        //For Uploading Picture
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                }
            }
        }

        //For Uploading Picture
        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can push the image onto the SDCard using DDMS FileExplorer or "adb push". Once you have  done that you need to run the Media Scanner.  The Media Scanner will scan the SDCard and add the images it finds to the MediaStore.  You can trigger the Media Scanner programatically or you can use the built-in Dev Tools app on the emulator.

Code to trigger Media Scanner programatically:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: thanks alot but where shall i type this code ?? can you explain more please I'm beginner in these things ... thanks in advance